# Maven Grails Plugin Environment

Tags: grails, maven-2, maven-plugin

how do I specify build goals like development, test or production environment in the maven grails plugin when packaging a war file for deployment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set it in the `<configuration>` section

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>maven-war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <env>prod</env>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `grails.env` when running maven:

```
mvn package -Dgrails.env=development
```

If you omit this option, the environment defaults to `production`.

Comment: Thank you, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: You can use this variable for any grails command. See Packaging and Running for Different Environments at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.2 Environments