# Grails environment config when running Maven goals

Tags: grails, maven, build, grails-maven

I am trying to build my grails project with Mavan and the maven-grails-plugin.

The plugin config in my pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${grails.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>init</goal>
          <goal>maven-clean</goal>
          <goal>validate</goal>
          <goal>config-directories</goal>
          <goal>maven-compile</goal>
          <goal>maven-test</goal>
          <goal>maven-war</goal>
          <goal>maven-functional-test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <env>build</env>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

My DataSource.groovy config looks like this:

```
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes"
        username = "dev"
        password = "dev"
    }
    hibernate {
        show_sql = true
    }
}
build {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=yes"
        username = "remote"
        password = "remote"
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run `mvn clean package` it tries to connect to the database using the development environment settings rather than the build environment settings.

As you can see Ive tried to specify the build environment using the  tag in the  element. As per this question-> [Maven Grails Plugin Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220121/maven-grails-plugin-environment)

Does anyone know how I can get this to use the build environment settings instead of the development ones?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `-Dgrails.env=build` command line parameter when calling maven.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what version of the plugin.
Maybe the

```
<grailsEnv>build</grailsEnv>
```

is a better configuration property?